# with flask admin tab create user, use the security.database.create_user method to update or create

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, flask-security

Im trying to se flask-admin and flask-security-too

and use the Views from flask-admin to administrate the users and its roles

the problem is that, the view from flask-admin is trying to update or create users with a standar db.commit() when the flask-security-too uses the method `create_user()` or in `security.datastore()`

so, i havent find a way to override this little error that avoids me to create or edit the erros

by the moment

i have tried

```
def form_action(self, form, model, ids):
```

and gives a error that form, model and ids arent posible to use

then i tried

```
def update_model(self, form, model, ids):
        try:
            user = security.datastore.find_user(id=ids)
            if user != None:
                username = model.username
                name = model.name
                email = model.email
                password = model.password
                user.username = username
                user.email = email
                user.name = name
                user.password = password
                security.datastore.update_user(user)
                security.datastore.commit()
                flash(f'usuario {user.name} fue editado con exito', 'success')
            else:
                username = model.username
                name = model.name
                email = model.email
                password = model.password
                user.username = username
                user.email = email
                user.name = name
                user.password = password
                security.datastore(user)
                security.datastore.commit()
                flash(f'usuario {user.name} fue editado con exito', 'success')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            flash('ups algo salio mal', 'danger')
```

and it still tries to update the database in the sqlalchemy ay without using the security methods. so it gives a problem in the fs_uniquifier `(1048, "Column 'fs_uniquifier' cannot be null")`

so any insigth is well apreciated

models.py

```
    class RolesUsers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles_users'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    role_id = db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

    # __str__ is required by Flask-Admin, so we can have human-readable 
    # values for the Role when editing a User.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # __hash__ is required to avoid the exception 
    # TypeError: unhashable type: 'Role' when saving a User
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    last_login_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    current_login_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    last_login_ip = db.Column(db.String(100))
    current_login_ip = db.Column(db.String(100))
    login_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    fs_uniquifier = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='roles_users',
                         backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Usuario {}>'.format(self.username)
```

the views.py

```
class UserModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
            return (current_user.is_active and
                    current_user.is_authenticated and
                    current_user.has_role('superuser')
            )
    column_exclude_list = ('password', 'fs_uniquifier', 'email')
    column_default_sort = 'name'
    can_delete = False

    #
    # exclude fileds that im not interested in render
    #
    form_excluded_columns = ('roles', 'last_login_at', 'current_login_at', 'last_login_ip', 'current_login_ip', 'login_count', 'fs_uniquifier', 'confirmed_at', 'password')

    #override the basic form to show fields that i want

    def scaffold_form(self):

        # Start with the standard form as provided by Flask-Admin. We've already told Flask-Admin to exclude the
        # password field from this form.
        form_class = super(UserModelView, self).scaffold_form()

        # Add a password field, naming it "password2" and labeling it "New Password".
        form_class.password2 = PasswordField('Nuevo Password',  [validators.InputRequired(), validators.EqualTo('password3', message='los passwords tienen que coincidir'), validators.Length(min=8, message='el password tiene que tener 8 digitos')])
        form_class.password3 = PasswordField('confirmar password')
        return form_class

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):

        # If the password field isn't blank...
        if model.password3 == model.password2:
            # ... then encrypt the new password prior to storing it in the database. If the password field is blank,
            # the existing password in the database will be retained.
            model.password = hash_password(model.password2)
        else:
            flash('ups, hay algo mal en el password')

    # add methods to use with flask security too and use the UserMixin of security
    #
    def update_model(self, form, model, ids):
        try:
            user = security.datastore.find_user(id=ids)
            if user != None:
                username = model.username
                name = model.name
                email = model.email
                password = model.password
                user.username = username
                user.email = email
                user.name = name
                user.password = password
                security.datastore.update_user(user)
                security.datastore.commit()
                flash(f'usuario {user.name} fue creado con exito', 'success')
            else:
                username = model.username
                name = model.name
                email = model.email
                password = model.password
                user.username = username
                user.email = email
                user.name = name
                user.password = password
                security.datastore(user)
                security.datastore.commit()
                flash(f'usuario {user.name} fue editado con exito', 'success')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            flash('ups algo salio mal', 'danger')

    @action('activar', 'activar usuarios', 'Seguro que quiere activar este usuario?')
    def activar(self, ids):
        try:
            user = security.datastore.find_user(id=ids)
            security.datastore.activate_user(user)
            security.datastore.commit()
            flash(f'usuario {user.name} fue activado', 'success')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            flash('ups algo salio mal', 'danger')

    @action('desactivar', 'desactivar usuarios', 'Seguro que quiere desactivar este usuario?')
    def desactivar(self, ids):
        try:
            user = security.datastore.find_user(id=ids)
            security.datastore.deactivate_user(user)
            security.datastore.commit()
            flash(f'usuario {user.name} fue desactivado', 'success')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            flash('ups algo salio mal', 'danger')
    @action('cerrar sesion', 'cerrar sesiones', 'Seguro que quieres cerrar todas sus sesiones?')
    def cerrar_sesion(self, ids):
        try:
            user = security.datastore.find_user(id=ids)
            security.datastore.set_uniquifier(user)
            security.datastore.commit()
            flash(f'usuario {user.name} fueron cerradas todas sus sesiones', 'success')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            flash('ups algo salio mal', 'danger')    

    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        # Override builtin _handle_view in order to redirect users when a view is not accessible.
        if not self.is_accessible():
            if current_user.is_authenticated:
            # permission denied
                abort(403)
            else:
                # login
                return redirect(url_for('security.login', next=request.url))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there is no `fs_uniquifier` field in your form, and thus it is not set in your `user` model. It is however required in your SQL table.

There are two different methods you can hook into to add the `fs_uniquifier` to your `user` model automatically.

**Method 1: When data is passed from the form to the model**

This is the method used in [flask-react-spa](https://github.com/briancappello/flask-react-spa/blob/master/backend/security/admins/user_admin.py), slightly adjusted.

In `views.py`:

```py
import uuid

# Import the Baseform from flask_admin...
from flask_admin.form import BaseForm

# extend it ...
class BaseUserForm(BaseForm):

    def populate_obj(self, user):
        super().populate_obj(user)
        if user.fs_uniquifier is None:
            user.fs_uniquifier = uuid.uuid4().hex

# and use the extended BaseForm for your view
class UserModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    form_base_class = BaseUserForm
    ...
```

This will then add a `fs_uniquifier` to your model if it is missing when you are populating your `user` object with data from a form.

**Method 2: Via the on_model_change event**

The second method hooks into the `on_model_change` event of your view, like you already did for the passwords.

In `views.py`:

```py
import uuid

class UserModelView(sqla.ModelView):

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if model.fs_uniquifier is None:
            model.fs_uniquifier = uuid.uuid4().hex
        ...
```

This will then add a `fs_uniquifier` to your model if it is missing when you are changing or creating a new `user` via the view.

Comment: it worked like a charm! it really fixed what I was trying to do! thank you very much!